# How to minify Javascript in D7

Tags: javascript, css-js-aggregation

I'm on rackspace's cloud sites service, so I can't modify my server environment. I'm also running Drupal 7. I've spent the last couple days looking for a way to minify JS in Drupal 7 and it is my conclusion that one does not exist yet. Am I wrong? Or do I need to wait for a D7 release of http://drupal.org/project/advagg?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to minify drupal's aggregated javascript (automatically)?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/484/what-is-the-best-way-to-minify-drupals-aggregated-javascript-automatically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Minify](https://drupal.org/project/minify) module to do the same. Minify module minify the JavaScript using Google compiler. It also works with "Aggregate JavaScript files" so you can also get advantage of combining multiple JavaScript files which is default option in Drupal 7.

Minify module also minify HTML.

Answer (score 3):

> List of modules in D7 that might provide similar functionality.
>   http://drupal.org/project/core_library
>   http://drupal.org/project/agrcache

It is what reported in the project page for [Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation](http://drupal.org/project/advagg), which is where your link takes to.

Comment: Core Library 1.x looks like it will do it, but it only serves static JS files. I've also had some minor problems with it in the past. Any other suggestions?