# How to minify JS and CSS in D7 without using modules

Tags: theming

One of the most promising D7 module http://drupal.org/project/advagg for minification and aggregation of CSS and JS isn't ready for production sites yet.

In such a situation which is the best option?

I also checked http://drupal.org/project/core_library but it sounds overkill.

What other good options we have inside or outside drupal?

Comment: The author of advagg is a regular here. Hopefully he will see this.

Comment: Have you tried the anwers given here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/484/what-is-the-best-way-to-minify-drupals-aggregated-javascript-automatically

Comment: One is advanced aggregation which I mentioned above that it's not production ready yet.Javascript aggregator is for D6 not D7.

Comment: Modules are the way to do non-core tasks in Drupal. Why do you want to hack around the way system is designed to use?

Comment: Outside of Drupal you would need some sort of build tool like Gulp if I am understanding the question right, but as @Mołot noted, that is what the modules are for.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a module, but the [Speedy](http://drupal.org/project/speedy) module minifies core JS, has a stable release, and is regularly updated.

Answer (score 3):

When you select "Aggregate and compress CSS files" check box from "Performance" it will minify the CSS.

Minify is a module, for Javascript you can use [Minify](https://drupal.org/project/minify) module to do the same. Minify module minify the JavaScript using Google compiler. It also works with "Boost" and "Aggregate JavaScript files" so you can also get advantage of combining multiple JavaScript files which is default option in Drupal 7.

Minify not only minify the Core JS, but also minify the custom JS.

Minify module also minify HTML.

For ref: [How to minify Javascript in D7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8173/how-to-minify-javascript-in-d7/101378)